# Problem with GRUB configuration

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have this problem with GRUB (using Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10)

```
grub-mkconfig no se pudo ejecutar satisfactoriamente. mensaje de error:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT: not found
```

---

English translation of the message:

```
grub-mkconfig failed to execute successfully. Error message:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT: not found
```

Comment: Did you edit any GRUB configuration files before you got this error?

Comment: Please could someone translate this?

Comment: Important part: " GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT: not found" Which says grub configuration is not correct. Probably easiest to use Boot-Repair and it advanced option to fully uninstall and reinstall of grub2. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair